# Basic movement 3D code not working properly

Tags: game-engine, godot

I wrote some code down for a kinematic character and only the W key(forward) worked, when I pressed w and d or a that's` when it starts moving but slowly goes left or right. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
  extends KinematicBody
var gravity =Vector3.DOWN * 12
var speed = 4
var jump_speed = 6
var spin = 0.1
var velocity = Vector3()
func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity += gravity * delta
    get_input()
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity,Vector3.UP)
func get_input():
    velocity.x = 0
    velocity.z = 0
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_UP"):
        velocity.z -= speed
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_DOWN"):
            velocity.x -= speed
        if Input.is_action_pressed("strafe_Right"):
            velocity.x -= speed
        if Input.is_action_pressed("strafe_Left"):
            velocity.z -= speed
func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event is  InputEventMouseMotion:
        rotate_y(-lerp(0, spin, event.relative.x/10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Um. Python code? Blocks are controlled by indentation. You've indented all your motion conditionals after move_UP so that they can only be executed if move_UP is active and executed first. Unindent the three "If" statements under the move_UP statement...

Comment: Well your solution did work but only for W and A, now D and S do left and forward too.

Comment: You did notice that you have the same action happening after "move_UP" and "strafe_Left" (`velocity_z -= speed`) and for "move_DOWN" and "strafe_Right" (`velocity_x -= speed`) ?

Comment: Oh sorry no i did not, I was following a tutorial that was in 3.1 and I am using 3.2, thanks so much.

Comment: Well now it seems like I am back to square one, I rearranged X and Z and it didnt really do anything.

Comment: Hrm. Seems to me that strafe_Left should do the opposite of strafe_Right: one should be `velocity_x += speed`, the other should be `velocity_x -= speed`. Same token, if move_UP is `velocity_z -= speed` then move_DOWN should be `velocity_z += speed`. But if that doesn't help I think we'd want to start a new question.

Comment: Sorry for late response, it worked thank you so much

Comment: GDScript, not Python. Although indentation works as in Python.